# What sort of use is this: ".. it is now clear that a number died"

Tags: word-usage

Recently France witnessed a terror-strike. On [Sky News](http://news.sky.com/story/1405106/hostages-killed-in-paris-supermarket-siege), the news has a following line:

> It was initially hoped that all hostages in the shop had been saved - but it is now clear that ***a number died.***

Now, I wonder that, shouldn't it be: "number of them died" or "a few died"?

I am confused about this usage-"a number died".

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly correct English. It's an ellipsis. It's understood as:

> ...but it is now clear that a number [of the hostages has] died.